# Test the uniform convergence of $x^n-x^{2n}$ in $[0,1]$

Tags: calculus, uniform-convergence

$$
f_n(x)=x^n-x^{2n}
\\
f_n:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb R
$$

I know that the function $x^n$ is not converging uniformally because the limiting function is not continuous (when x=1 there's a "step" in the graph). Here There exists no such step. I'm thinking about using Weierstrass' M-test but not sure which $M_n$ to pick.

Any hints?

Comment: I would locate the maximum of $f_n(x)$ in $[0,1]$.  It seems fairly clear that $f_n(x) \ge 0$ on that bounded interval, so...

Answer (score 0):

Note that $f$ is differentiable and $f'(x)=nx^{n-1}-2nx^{2n-1}$ which means that $f$ has extrema at

$$n-2nx^{n}=0$$

or $(1/2)^{1/n}$. As a commenter noted, $f(x)\ge 0$ on that interval so you have a maximum. If you plug in the value of $x$, does the bound go to zero as $n$ grows?